# adding random number in python

Tags: python, function, random, numbers

I am trying to create a function in python that adds a random number to the parameter of the function. Then, I need to pass an array to this function so it adds a random number to each element. Can you help?

Comment: Edit your question to add what you have tried so far.

Answer (score -1):

```
from random import randint

def add_num(x):
    return x + randint(0, 10)

def add_nums(arr):
    return [add_num(x) for x in arr]
```